# Focus error in IE8 when not focusing

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, tabcontrol

I upgraded my site from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0 a few weeks ago, including an upgrade of my ajax toolkit. Tested with IE9, FF, and Chrome, and it all worked fine.

I now noticed that 3 of my pages no longer load properly in IE8.  I get:

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;
>   Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; BRI/2; InfoPath.3; AskTbORJ/5.13.1.18107; BO1IE8_v1;ENUS) Timestamp: Wed, 11 Jan 2012
>   16:32:11 UTC

Message: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.

All 3 pages contain ajax tab controls with more than 10 tabs and not much else. The message says it's a focus problem, but I'm not setting the focus anywhere.  They were working before the upgrade, and since then I haven't changed anything more complex than ForeColor on my error messages. I have other pages with ajax tab controls that are working perfectly.

I've been googling all day, but nothing I've seen seems to work.

EDIT: I've narrowed down the problem somewhat. Error shows when there are nested tab controls.

Comment: check this http://forums.asp.net/t/1404295.aspx/1   and this http://sandblogaspnet.blogspot.com/2009/04/setting-focus-to-particular-tab-in.html

Comment: Both of those assume I'm setting the focus. As I said, I'm not.

Comment: You are not, but probably the code of tab control do. Get the source code to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a problem with the November release of the AJAX Control Toolkit

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27053